# How to Compile Vim8 for 32bit iOS

Tags: c, vim, cross-platform, cross-compiling, jailbreak

I want a 32bit version of Vim8 for iOS, how can I compile it myself, or is there an existing one?

Or does vim8 even support 32bit device?

I want that in my jailbreak iPhone5, the existing vim7 I installed have some problem: when in the insert mode, I press the direction key, I got a letter instead.

I install the vim8 to my jailbreak iPhone X, it doesn't have the issue. and that vim8 is for arm64, I can not use it on my jailbreak iPhone 5.

So any one have any idea about that?

Comment: I assume you've tried the usual `set nocompatible` in the `.vimrc` file on your iPhone 5?

Comment: new to vim, that command solve my problem. btw I want the vimrc work to all users in iOS, I make this files: `/etc/vimrc`, `vim /etc/.vimrc`,  `/etc/vim/vimrc`, `/etc/vim/.vimrc`, `~/.vimrc`. only the last one is loaded. I am sonfuse why make this kind of things so hard.

Comment: Weird, usually vim checks those places. The only thing that comes to mind is that vim doesn't have permission to read files from those other locations, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It might be the access issue. And I want to know how to find out which vimrc file will be loaded. Is there a commad for vim I can use or a document that will list all the vimrc file will be loaded.

Comment: Never mind, just found it - [location of vimrc file](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file). And thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

This problematic behavior is a [fairly well-known issue](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell) that arises due to some funky business between Vim's vi-compatible mode and the terminal it's running from.

In OP's case, there wasn't a `.vimrc` file on their iPhone 5, and since Vim defaults to vi-compatible mode, this issue arose.

The solution to this was to create that file, `~/.vimrc`, and paste the below code in there:

```
set nocompatible
```